# How to use wxBusyInfo?

Tags: wxwidgets

I have encountered a problem with wxBusyInfo.
I want to disable user's operation when doing some calculation.
I just write the code like this:

```
wxWindowDisabler disableAll;
wxBusyInfo info(_T("Working, please wait..."), this);
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
Install();
}
```

In the Install() function, I do some work like this:

```
wxSleep();
wxExecute(cmd, output, errors);
```

When I run the application, the busyinfo dialog will show up, but it will no longer at the top of the application. Also after I click the application, or click the busyinfo dialog, it will turn out like the pictures attached. When the Install() function finished, it will be ok. But I don't want users can end the application by that way.
What's the problem? What can I do?
[after click the applicatioin](http://bbs.nju.edu.cn/file/J/jamesyang/busyinfo.png)
[after click the busyinfo dialog](http://bbs.nju.edu.cn/file/J/jamesyang/busyinfo2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling wxExecute synchronously, which means that it does not return until `cmd completes.` So you application does not get a chance to update the display.

So, you need to call wxExecute asynchronously.

The snag is that you cannot then see the output and errors from the executed command.